# Localization and mapping using RGB-D sensor?

Tags: ros, navigation, odometry, data, depth

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

I would like to use a RGB-Sensor for example the Asus Xtion Pro Live Sensor that have Infrared Projector, RGB Camera and IR camera that combine depth data and visual information for fast robot localization and 3D Mapping. So is there any analysis of the current state of the art algorithms and also some help of advantages and disadvantages of this method? Where I can find more information and also some critical analysis regarding the implementation and usefulness for indoor and outdoor localization?

Which ros package can be used in these case??

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61252/localization-and-mapping-using-rgb-d-sensor?/) by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on ROS Answers with karma: 330 on 2013-04-21

Post score: -1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Scientific informations (to give you a starting point):

- [Google Scholar](http://scholar.google.de/)
- [CiteSeerX](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/)
- [ACM Digital Library (requires an account)](http://dl.acm.org/)
- [IEEE Xplore Digital Library (requires an account)](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/)

---

ROS package (first hit if using google for "ros rgbd slam" btw): [rgbdslam](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rgbdslam)

This package is used quite often and actively maintained. So you will find a lot of informations about it here on ros answers.

---

Originally posted by [Ben_S](https://answers.ros.org/users/1072/ben_s/) with karma: 2510 on 2013-04-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2